# JSON: how do you add to a field that doesn't have a key?

Tags: javascript, json, indexing, key

I have a simple JSON object

```js
simple_chart_config = {
    chart: {
        container: "#tree-simple"
    },

    nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Question" },
        children: [
        {
            text: { name: "Answer 1" }
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

And I'd like to add a new subfield within the first entry on the `children` array so that the final output is

```js
simple_chart_config = {
    chart: {
        container: "#tree-simple"
    },

    nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Question" },
        children: [
        {
            text: { name: "Answer 1" },
            children: [
            {
                text: { name: "Question 2" }
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

I've tried several methods, such as

```js
var questionTwoStr = '{"children": [{"text": { "name": "Question 2" }}]}'
var questionTwo = JSON.parse(questionTwoStr);
simple_chart_config.nodeStructure.children[0] = questionTwo;
```

but I'm having issues working out all of the nested indexes in my head. This is for a tree in treant.js if that context is helpful at all.

I think I'm mostly confused because the place I'm trying to add the new subfield doesn't have a key, which I thought was required for JSON.

Comment: So the only JSON here is what you're attempting to do with `questionTwoStr`. Is there a reason you're trying to use JSON for that? Why not just create is as an object in the first place? `simple_chart_config.nodeStructure.children[0].children = [{text: { name:"Question 2" }}];

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do, thank you so much! I think I have a bit of a fundamental misunderstanding of when to use JSON vs just a normal JS object. Much obliged!

Comment: JSON is for data-interchange where sending the actual structure isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use JSON here; you can add the object itself:
`simple_chart_config.nodeStructure.children[0].children = [{text: { name:"Question 2" }}];`